# How I create custom page template in parallax theme Wordpress

Tags: themes, parallax

I am not able to create custom page template in wordpress with installed parallax theme template

Answer (score 0):

This would be done in the same way as any WordPress template.

First of all, make a child theme:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Make a copy of your page.php file and rename it to something relevant e.g. page-custom.php

Then, start the custom page off with the following code:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: My Custom Page
*/
```

and make any changes that you need to. It's all covered in the codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates

Comment: Thanks for your help.. so you mean to create any new custom template i need to create child theme

Comment: You don't *have* to, but it's definitely recommended. If you don't and you update your theme then you will lose any changes.

Comment: the child theme is already created for the homepage.. now i have created a new page named as fitment and i want add some custom code to it
what do i do?

what i did before..
i created a custom template asusal in wordpress.. and its name shows in the edit page
but this fitment page still showing the default page

Comment: Maybe your custom code isn't working? Quick way to test a custom page template would be to add an h1 to the top (e.g. <h1>Testing<h1/>) - if that h1 shows up then you can be sure that the custom template is being used.

Comment: this is my testing page
http://nomessdrainplug.com/fitment/

this is my fitment edit page screenshot
http://nomessdrainplug.com/test.png
and this is what i write in template

<?php
/*
Template Name: Fitment Filter
*/

?>
<div class="hello">
<h1>hello hwo are you</h1>
</div>

Comment: It looks like you have a "coming soon" plugin installed, so I can't see it. But if you follow the instructions in the codex it should work.

Comment: here is my fitment page screenshot

 nomessdrainplug.com/test1.png

Comment: is there any other help?